# Cannot Connect to my ISP login page

Tags: dns, wireless-router, opendns

I'm using a Belkin Wireless router. For about a month I have been using DNS crypt from OpenDNS.

About two days ago, I was experiencing connectivity issues when I attempt to login into my ISP login page.  My ISP uses a different DNS server address, the ISP's login page can only be connected through their DNS server, so to overcome that I hardcoded the ip address of my ISP login page in hosts file.  When OpenDNS is active, I still could connect to my ISP login page.

About two days ago I could not login to my ISP's login page and I thought it was a problem with my ISP, so I called them, they said everything is fine with my network.

I uninstalled DNScrypt (as a test) and tried to connect, still no joy. Sometimes it would connect to my login page and most of times it shows:

> login.hathway.com was interrupted.

After logging in, I can connect to every website. When I enter the login page. It can't connect even when i can connect to every other website.

When I connect to my Computer to LAN cable it will work fine. I even can't login through my iPod touch. When I troubleshoot my connection it gives me following message:

> The connection between your access point router or cable modem and the internet is broken.

I checked everything the cables are fine. Now I can see that the problem is only when I connect to login page of my ISP. If I'm using my ISP's DNS address, I can connect to the login page. The problem is when I use a different DNS address it cant resolve my ISP's login page address. as it can only be resolved using my ISP's DNS server, I checked  my DNS setting in my computer and in wireless router setting they are set to:

> Obtain DNS server address automatically.

Log of `ipcofig /all`:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Manoj-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : Belkin

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Belkin
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR9002WB-1NG Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 74-2F-68-99-99-21
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3895:9e5d:e27d:6f1a%14(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.3(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, June 19, 2012 4:45:49 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, July 26, 2148 11:51:36 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 376713064
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-11-D8-DC-14-DA-E9-5F-6D-BF
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 14-DA-E9-5F-6D-BF
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9c4d:86df:c531:37b2%11(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.27.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 184569942
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-11-D8-DC-14-DA-E9-5F-6D-BF
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::242f:5140:5512:dbdb%12(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.121.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 218124374
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-11-D8-DC-14-DA-E9-5F-6D-BF
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.Belkin:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Belkin
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{D77F4D2A-0814-49A2-87B9-AD334A9CDFF4}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{90D5B4D0-D03F-40F9-9CF1-1F4ADA50D775}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I do not want to reinstall windows because I have the SAP Developer Preview version installed on my computer and it took nearly 7 hours to install it. I am not really confident that I can configure the software again, the first time I was lucky.

Comment: I tried to reset my router to factory setting..still no joy :((

Comment: You need to figure out how to install SAP its not that hard.

Comment: Could you please point me to some documents..where there are step by step instructions to install ABAP developer version and configure WEb dynpro and Adobe forms. Its a request.Thank you

Comment: There are lots documentation on that I would find it using the same tools you do.

Comment: "in wireless router setting they are set to Obtain DNS server address automatically." - have you unchecked this in the router, and manually entered your ISPs DNS yet?  I don't mean manually at your computer.  I mean in the router itself.  Any DNS settings you enter at your computer should not affect OTHER devices that connect to your router.  Oh, and don't forget to power cycle both the modem and router after you do.

Answer (score 0):

```
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
```

Change the DNS Servers to your ISP's DNS Servers to see if it works.  Once you do that set your router to use your DNS Servers as a third and fourth DNS Server that should solve your problem.

Comment: i have tried...still no joy...ISP login isnt at all..loading
`Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to login.hathway.com`
previous it said `connection is interrupted`

Comment: i tries System restore..but i dont know..but it failing..

Comment: @bobby - After you set the DNS Servers on your PC for your `Wireless Connection` and performed an ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew you still get this error?  When you added the third and fourth DNS servers on your router did you release and renew on the router itself?

Comment: hhey 192.168.2.1 goes to my router settings page.is it common

Comment: I tried ipconfig /release and /renew with third and fourth dns address still same problem

Comment: @bobby - Just use your ISP's DNS server.  The directions I provided worked for me when I had this problem.

Comment: i tried, it didnt work :((